# How do I properly set wget to download only new files?

Tags: linux, terminal, wget

Let's say there's an url, let's call it `http://www.some-url.com/folder/`

This location has directory listing **enabled**, therefore I can do this:

```
wget -r -np http://www.some-url.com/folder/
```

To download all its contents with all the files and subfolders and their files.

Now, what should I do if I want to repeat this process again, a month later, and I don't want to download everything again, only add new/changed files?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

did you read this ? http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html

"Several days later, you would like Wget to check if the remote file has changed, and download it if it has."

```
wget -N http://www.some-url.com/folder/
```

Try this.

Comment: But -N is useless if retrieved file has not Last-Modified header.

Comment: @unibasil but how do you know, if the retrieved file has Last-Modified header?

Comment: Also if the download was interrupted, a wget -N will reuse the downloaded index files, and assume the previous job finished.  Nuke the index.html*s first, then wget -N.

Answer (score 21):

```
wget -c
```

also continues partial files caused when the download has issues.....
Better yet,

```
 wget -c -N
```

seems to do both at the same time.

Comment: I found with my version `1.11.4 Red Hat modified`, these flags are not compatible and -c overrides -N.

Comment: `-c` option of `wget` helped mw the sync partially downloaded file from url. Its really a good option to use if faced any network problems while downloading.

Comment: I can confirm Matt Williamson's observation, using the `-c` flag nullifies the effect of `-N`, meaning newer files will not get downloaded.